# jquery post method to send javascript array to php doesn't work for me, why?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, post

I was looking over the web how to send Java script array, like this one:

```
var array = ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"];"
```

To php file on my server.

Then I came across jQuery `.post()` method, but when I use it my php file remains empty!

The code I was using is:

```
var array = ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post( 'hs.php', array, function(data, statusText) {
        alert("Uploaded")
    });
})
```

But I have no much experience with php and I don't know should php be empty or have some code to retrieve array! All I want is to store javascript array on server file so I can read that array again on page load.

What am I doing wrong?
Can someone show short example of working html and php code?

Comment: You can't send "an array", only strings. There are several ways you could serialise an array for transmission over HTTP. You need to deserialise it using a matching method. What code are you using to send it? What code are you using to decode it? What errors are reported? How can the "php file" be empty? It has to have program code in it for it to do anything. Do you mean you get a blank response? If so, then add debug code to figure out what is going on.

Comment: OK, i was try like this:  

var array = ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"]

$(document).ready(function() {
$.post(
  'hs.php',
  array,
  function(data, statusText) {
    alert("Uploaded")
  }
);
})

But I have no much experience with php and I don't know should php be empty or have some code to retrieve array!

All I want is to store javascript array on server file so I can read that array again on page load!

Comment: Look at the [docs for data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) — it takes a string or an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for this. [JSON encode](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/JSONEncoder) the javascript array and send it to your php and [decode the json-decoded array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on server side.

JSON is a standard notation which converts objects (arrays, class objects etc) to string notation, which can be passed via http.

POST variables are stored in `data` option of jQuery post/ajax. Now lets say you want to pass following array to php:

```
var my_array = ["my", "name", "is", "foo", "bar"];
```

You can then json encode it using jQuery's JSON encoding plugin.

```
var my_json_val = $.JSON.encode(my_array);
```

Then you can pass this value to server using:

```
$.post({
url: 'my_url',
data: { my_json_name: my_json_val}
});
```

At server side you can do this:

```
$my_json_encoded = $_POST['my_json_name'];
$my_json_val = json_decode($my_json_encoded);
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, I know there is a way to do tha using JSON but I simply can't figure out how to use it with javascript array and send it to php! If you can at least direct me to some beginner tutorial or direct me to right direction?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm really novice with this, so I need to clarify a little your answer! 
I understand that first 3 script I need to put in html code and add jQuery's JSON encoding plugin. But where to put fourth script? and should "url: 'my_url'," in third script,  be my php file like url: 'test.php' or something else?

Comment: OK here is the link: http://kineticstudio.x10.mx/hs 
You can see in html that I was added jQueru's JSON plugin and first tree scripts you posted. In php file I was added fourth script you posted. and when I try php remains untouched! Why?